# A linear algebra problem related to system of linear difference equations

Tags: linear-algebra

In the teory of system of linear difference equations, I have the following fact:

If $A\alpha − B$ is singular for all $\alpha$, then its rows are linearly dependent, and
hence there exists a matrix polynomial $\psi(\alpha)$ such that:

$$\psi(\alpha) (A\alpha − B) = 0 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad(*)$$

identically in $\alpha$.

How can I prove the existence of $\psi$ and the $(*)$ equation?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sense of this, I'm assuming that $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices over a field $\mathbb F$ with more than $n$ elements, and $A \alpha - B$ is singular for every $\alpha \in \mathbb F$.  Thus $\det(A\alpha - B)$, which is a polynomial in $\alpha$ of degree at most $n$, has more than $n$ zeros, and therefore is identically $0$.  Thus, as a matrix over the field $\mathbb F(\alpha)$ of rational functions in the indeterminate $\alpha$ over $\mathbb F$, $A \alpha - B$ is singular, and therefore it has linearly dependent rows, i.e. there is a row vector $v(\alpha)$ with entries in $\mathbb F(\alpha)$, not all $0$, such that $v(\alpha) (A \alpha - B) = 0$.  Multiplying by a common denominator, we can get $\psi(\alpha)$ whose entries are polynomial in $\alpha$.